# Removing dead content provider . Just killing application directly

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I am making an application for sms banning .In this i am widely using contact ContentProvider .
I am using this "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI" URI to fetch all data of a contact to display it in list.

I am facing strange problem in which my application gets killed directly , its activity thread kills itself ,even it goes to onCreate method but not to onPause or onDestroy method.

I am using timer to show notification after some time , thing is when user do back press , it wipes out my application from memory with timer running in background as separate thread.After timer completes some seconds , i am opening my activity to show new notifications to user .

But as i told , it goes to onCreate do some processing , like loading contacts , and just wipe out .

I am not getting anything , as i am not receiving any error .
What i am receiving is just a single statement :  Removing dead content provider

Please give me guidance .

Comment: Have you checked the logs? It seems likely that your app is killed due to some exception.

Comment: Yes i checked , but as i told ,it printed nothing , but a single line  in my logcat
"Removing dead content provider".

Comment: I have no better suggestion than use the debugger to find the glitch. Use the Exception breakpoint feature to stop the app automatically on any exceptions. Here is how to activate is http://bit.ly/14xkMJO